# PySpark groupBy and aggregation functions with multiple columns

Tags: pyspark, group-by

I work with a spark Dataframe and I try to create a new table with aggregation using groupby :
My data example :
[image]

and this is the desired result :
[image]

I tried this code `data.groupBy("id1").agg(countDistinct("id2").alias("id2"), sum("value").alias("value"))`

Anyone can help please ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([('id11', 'id21', 1), ('id11', 'id22', 2), ('id11', 'id23', 3), ('id12', 'id21', 2), ('id12', 'id23', 1), ('id13', 'id23', 2), ('id13', 'id21', 8)], ["id1", "id2","value"])
```

*Aggregated Data* -

```
df.groupBy("id1").agg(count("id2"),sum("value")).show()
```

**Output** -

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id1|count(id2)|sum(value)|
+----+----------+----------+
|id11|         3|         6|
|id12|         2|         3|
|id13|         2|        10|
+----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution of how to groupBy with multiple columns using PySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.groupBy("id1").agg(F.count(col("id2")).alias('id2_count'),                     
                      F.sum(col('value')).alias("value_sum")).show()
```